# Gain back permissions to run commands on DigitalOcean Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, system-recovery

I accidentally ran "sudo chmod o-x /" on a remote Ubuntu system (with DigitalOcean). Now, no commands can be run on the server at all (so login doesn't work). How do you fix this?

Comment: If you cannot login as **root**, probably no fix available.  You might be able to recover the machine by mounting its system disk on a second machine.

Comment: Hmm... yeah, even with root, ssh doesn't allow any logins. Thanks, will look into that!

Answer (score 2):

Boot into [recovery](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-recover-from-file-system-corruption-using-fsck-and-a-recovery-iso) on your droplet and you should be able to at least login after fixing some permissions.

You might need some trial and error on which directories will be necessary. I'd start with `/bin`, `/sbin`, `/usr/bin` etc.